# The construction of inductive limit topology from an inductive system

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

I was reading about inductive limit topology from the book "A course in Functional Analysis" by J B Conway for its use later. In the section solely dedicated to inductive limits (and distributions), the author defines an inductive system in the following way:

**Definition** (Inductive system): A pair $(X_i, \left\lbrace X_i : i \in I \right\rbrace)$ is an inductive system if $X$ is a vector space, each $X_i$ is a linear manifold (vector subspace) of $X$, each $X_i$ has a topology $\mathscr{T}_i$ which is locally convex such that

1. $I$ is a directed set and whenever $i \leq j$ (with $i, j \in I$), we have $X_i \subseteq X_j$.
2. Whenever $i \leq j$ and $U_j \in \mathscr{T}_j$, we have $U_j \cap X_i \in \mathscr{T}_i$.
3. $X = \bigcup\limits_{i \in I} X_i$.

With this definition in hand, the author goes on to define the inductive limit topology as follows:

First, we define $\mathcal{B}$ to be the collection of all the balanced convex sets $V$ such that for all $i \in I$, we have $V \cap X_i \in \mathscr{T}_i$. Using $\mathcal{B}$, we define the collection $\mathscr{T}$ to be the collection of all the sets $U \subseteq X$ such that for every $x_0 \in U$, there is an element $V \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x_0 + V \subseteq U$. The collection $\mathscr{T}$ forms a topology on $X$ and is then called the inductive limit topology.

Now, I do not find any trouble with the definition of an inductive system or the inductive limit topology. However, what does concern me at this moment is how do we know $\mathcal{B}$ is non-empty? Once it is non-empty, everything fits into place nicely. I am sure I am missing something very small (one can even call it "trivial"). Any help regarding this will be appreciable!

For reference, a set $V \subseteq X$ will be a balanced set if for all $x \in V$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}$ with $\left| \alpha \right| \leq 1$, we have $\alpha x \in V$.

Comment: $\mathcal B$ is not empty because $X\in\mathcal B$.

Comment: And there are examples where $X$ is the only element of $\mathcal B$.

Comment: Yes! I completely missed that! @Jochen could you provide some source or those examples?

Comment: MO is a good resource: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/221476/do-hausdorff-locally-convex-inductive-limits-always-exist/221478#221478